# show progress during processing big data

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a question I have a web app that to run need to process some big file. It can take a 5secund so meantime I want to show user that file is processing or the best will be to send information how many time to end. This is the first page and I cannot send twice res.render so how to do this?

```
 var fileinarray = require('./readfile');

 app.get('/', function(req, res){
     var dataready = fileinarray; 
     res.render('index', {data: dataready});
 });
```

So how I can do his? I read a little about socke.io but I don't now how to used in my case?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are loading a page (which it looks like) with this request, then you can't show progress with the way you have it structured because the browser is waiting to download your page and thus can't show anything in that window until you render the page for it.  But, you want to show progress before the page gets there.

So, you have to restructure the way things work.  First off, in order to show progress, the browser has to have a working page that you can show progress in.  That means the browser can't be waiting for the page to arrive.  The most straightforward way I can think of to do this is to render a shell page initially that your server returns immediately (no waiting for the original content).  In that shell page, you have code to show progress and you initiate a request to your server to fetch the long running data.  There are several ways this could be done using Ajax and webSockets.  I'll outline some combinations:

**All with Ajax**

1. Browser requests the / page and your server renders the shell page
2. Meanwhile, after rendering the page, the server starts the long running process of fetching the desired data.
3. Rendered inside the shell page is a Javascript variable that contains a transaction ID
4. Meanwhile, client-side Javascript can regularly send Ajax requests to the server to check on the progress of the given transaction id (say every 10 seconds).  The server returns whatever useful progress info and client-side Javascript displays the progress info.
5. At some point the server is done with the data and one of the regular Ajax requests that was checking on progress returns with all the data.  The client-side Javascript then inserts this data into the current page and the operation is complete.

**Mostly with WebSocket**

1. Browser requests the / page and your server renders the shell page
2. Client-side code inside the shell page makes a webSocket or socket.io connection to the server and sends an initial request for the data that belongs with this page.
3. The server receives the webSocket connection and the initial request for the data and starts the long running process of fetching the data.
4. As the server has meaningful progress information, it sends that to the client over the webSocket/socket.io connection and when the client receives that information, it renders appropriate progress in the page.
5. At some point the server is done fetching the data and sends the client a message containing the final data.  The client-side Javascript receives this data and inserts it into the page.
6. The client can then close the webSocket/socket.io connection.

Comment: sorry, but how to renders the shell page on a client side using node? I cannot found any information how to do this in node?

Comment: @cyprian - In the `app.get()` that you show in your question, you render the shell page there.  And, then you use client-side Javascript that is in that shell page to fetch the actual content (using either of the methods I've outlined), show progress and then insert the final content into the shell page.

Comment: ok, thx now I understand. And I think that websocket will be the best from my site, cos almost all my content depends from the receiving data. And using socket I can easily send partial data and dynamically create content. Again Thx